# RJS error: TypeError: element is null

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, rjs

I got RJS error: TypeError: element is null while using ajax.

I used  in view

```
<%= periodically_call_remote(:url=>{:action=>'get_user_list', :id=>'1'},
:frequency => '5') %>
```

in controller

```
  render :update do |page|
    page.replace_html  'chat_area', :partial => 'chat_area', :object => [@chats, @user]     if @js_update
  end
```

in partial chat_area

```
<% if !@chats.blank? && !show_div(@chats).blank?%>
    <% show_div_id=show_div(@chats) %>
  <% for chat in @chats %>
      <div class="popup" id="chat_area_<%= chat.id %>"
style="display:<%= (chat.id == show_div_id)? 'block' : 'none' %>;">

        <% form_remote_for(:chat, :url => {:controller=>'chats',
:action=>'create', :id=>1}, :html=>{:name => "form_#{chat.id}"},
:complete=>"resetContent('#{chat.id}');") do |f| %>
        <div style="display:none;">
            <%= f.hidden_field :sessionNo, :value=>chat.sessionNo %>
            <%= f.text_area :chatContent,  :id=>
"chatContent_field_#{chat.id}", :cols=>"100", :rows=>"6",
:onKeyPress=>"return submitenter(this,event);" %>
          </div>
            <input type="image" src="images/chat/send-hover.png"
value="Send" onclick="return submit_button('<%= chat.id %>')"/>
        <% end %>
      </div>

    </div>
  <% end %>

<% else %>
      <div class="popup" id="chat_area_none" style="display:'block';">
          <input type="image" disabled ="disabled"
src="images/chat/send.png" style="cursor:default;" value="Send" />
      </div>
<% end %>
```

My div present in index.html.erb

```
      <table border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tbody><tr>
            <td align="left" width="80%" valign="top" style="">
              <%= text_area :chat, :chatContent,  :id=> "chatContent_field", :cols=>"100", :rows=>"6" %>
            </td>
            <td align="left" width="20%" valign="bottom" style="padding-left:10px;padding-left:10px;x" >
              <div id="chat_area">
                 <%= render :partial => 'chat_area' %>
              </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Regards,

Salil Gaikwad

Comment: Element is null means that there is DOM element on the page that the returned javascript is trying to access that cannot be found. I cannot see the issue immediately, but that is what the error means.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I find it out why it happens because I didn't close div above the "chat_area" properly.
the only thing i did isclose the div and it works like a magic,
neways thanks to all

Reagrds,

Salil Gaikwad

Answer (score 1):

This means that RJS is attempting to manipulate something in html output that doesn't exist.

It looks like the problem is that you want to update your `user_list` but nothing with that id exists in your html. Make sure you are rendering that, also make sure you have the `update` attribute in your `periodically_call_remote` method set to the id of the element you want to update.

```
periodically_call_remote(:url => { :action => 'get_user_list' }, :update => 'get_user_list')
```